# Golang elasticache cleint to Redis client

Tags: go, redis, amazon-elasticache, go-redis

I am creating an elasticache client using below snippet

```
import(
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/elasticache"
"github.com/go-redis/redis"
)
// Create a ElastiCache client from just a session.
s, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(S3_REGION)})
svc := elasticache.New(s)
```

//I have developed my code using go-redis client

```
redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     c.host,
    Password: "",
    DB:       c.dbIndex)
```

how can I use the elasticache from aws-sdk to work with redis client ? I am very new to this and I am lost .

Comment: the two packages are for different purposes, `aws-sdk/service/elasticache` is for managing(creating,updating,deleting) your elasticache instance. While `go-redis/redis` package is the right one for you to caching your data into elasticache